# How should I be reading this code?

Tags: php

So I'm trying to read this legacy code - am I reading this wrong, or is the code repeating itself multiple times? It seems like it is assigning $cuid multiple different times in multiple different ways - is it getting different values somehow? The only two ways I can see are via cookie and via GET request.

```
$id = "";
$cuid = "";
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
    $id = $_SESSION['id'];
    $cuid = $id;
    $valid_user = $_SESSION['valid_user'];
    $cuname = $_SESSION['cuname'];
    $website = $_SESSION['website'];
    $site = $website;
    $email_contact = $_SESSION['email_contact'];

}
$cuid = $_GET['cuid'];
include_once("dbfunctions.php");
if (isset($_SESSION['id']))  {
    $cuid = $_SESSION['id'];
} elseif (isset($cuid)) {
    $_SESSION['id'] = $cuid;
}
```

EDIT: Ok, now how would I have it use $_GET['cuid'], if $_GET['cuid'] had a value, no matter what. Basically, several sites use this, and we want a user to be able to navigate from several of them, and get a different logo each time, but if they don't navigate from other sites, to keep the same logo throughout their experience.

I would just check to see if $_GET['cuid'] had a value, and if it did, to do nothing else, correct, but if it did not, check for a $_SESSION['id']. Am I on the right path?

Comment: That is definitely bad and redundant code.  It could be reduced by half.  You should share this with CSI: PHP.  http://csiphp.com/blog/

Comment: It pulls `cuid` from the querystring (GET).  However, if `$_SESSION['id']` is set then it sets `cuid` to that session variable.   Then on the `elseif`, it sets  `$_SESSION['id']` to the querystring `cuid` if there's no `$_SESSION['id']` set already.

Comment: it looks like **bad** legacy code :D

Comment: I agree with @DuaneGran.  This could have been almost a single line.

Answer (score 2):

You can rewrite the whole thing as follow:

```
$id = "";
$cuid = $_GET['cuid'];
include_once("dbfunctions.php");

session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
    $id = $_SESSION['id'];
    $cuid = $id;
    $valid_user = $_SESSION['valid_user'];
    $cuname = $_SESSION['cuname'];
    $website = $_SESSION['website'];
    $site = $website;
    $email_contact = $_SESSION['email_contact'];

} else
   $_SESSION['id'] = $cuid;
```

Comment: that won't save the id in the get-param into the session if not already set

Comment: That's not an equivalent code. You forgot the part that set $_SESSION['cuid'] to $_GET['cuid'] if it was not defined previously

Comment: what are you talking about? there isn't anythinh like $_SESSION['cuid']

Comment: sorry, I meant $_SESSION['id']. It's definitely there. But I see that you have added that to your example now ;-)

Comment: dunno If i got what you meant but i added an else stmt maybe that fixes you

Answer (score 1):

You can ignore all code related to `$cuid` until the line that says

```
$cuid = $_GET['cuid'];
```

It doesn't matter what `$cuid` was set to previously, because it is set to the contents of `$_GET` no matter what.

So to summarize:

- `$cuid` is set to `$_GET['cuid']` by default
- If it is stored in the session, the value is retrieved from there
- If it is **not** stored in session, it is saved to session using the current value

Or explained using code:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
    $cuid = $_SESSION['id'];
}
else {
    $cuid = $_GET['cuid'];
    $_SESSION['id'] = $cuid;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it would be enough to test for `isset($_SESSION['id'])` and setting `$cuid` (and maybe `$id` if that is used further on) to the session id. In an else-block the `$cuid` can be set to `$_GET['id']` and `$_SESSION['id']` set to that.